# Why my select Distinct is not working in my sql

Tags: sql, distinct

I have an SQL table and it contains duplicate values(musteri_id,musteri_kod,musteri_ad). So I used `distinct` keyword, but it is not working for me.

Musteri_id,musteri_kod, and musteri_ad they have many duplicate values my SQL is working and I do not get any error but I see duplicate values in my datatable. Thanks

```
 select distinct m2.musteri_id,
             m2.musteri_versiyon,
             m2.musteri_kod,
             m2.musteri_ad as musteri_ad,
             m2.tck_no,
             m2.vkn_no,
             m2.pasaport_no,
             m2.istisna_kod,
             b.banka_kod,
             bs.sube_kod
        from banka b
       inner join banka_sube bs
          on (bs.banka_id = b.banka_id)
       inner join musteri_rol mrb
          on (mrb.musteri_rol_id = b.banka_id)
       inner join musteri m1
          on (m1.musteri_id = mrb.musteri_id)
       inner join musteri_rol mrs
          on (mrs.musteri_rol_id = bs.sube_id)
       inner join musteri m2
          on (m2.musteri_id = mrs.musteri_id)
       where ((m2.musteri_ad like
             '%' || 'GARANTİ' || '%') and 'GARANTİ' is not null)
             --and( m2.vkn_no is  null or b.banka_kod is  null or bs.sube_kod is  null)
      union
      select distinct m.musteri_id,
             m.musteri_versiyon,
             m.musteri_kod,
             m.musteri_ad,
             m.tck_no,
             m.vkn_no,
             m.pasaport_no,
             m.istisna_kod,
             null banka_kod,
             null sune_kod
        from musteri_rol mr
       inner join musteri m
          on (m.musteri_id = mr.musteri_id)
       where mr.rol_id = 2701      
         and (m.musteri_ad like '%' || 'GARANTİ' || '%' and
             'GARANTİ' is not null or 'GARANTİ' is null);
```

Comment: If you can, please edit your question to include a few records of the duplicate data you are getting - it would help us help you.

Comment: musteri_id :40864  musteri_kod :40864 musteri_ad :xx                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                 
 musteri_id :40865  musteri_kod :40865 musteri_ad :yy                                                  musteri_id :40865  musteri_kod :40865 musteri_ad :yy

Comment: Union itself is enough to remove duplicates. There must be a single value which is causing the duplicates.

Comment: @just: **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and provide the sample data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). Don't put that in comments. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Remember that SELECT DISTINCT works om the whole selected rows.

Comment: Simplify your problem. [mcve]

Comment: Do you really have duplicate rows, i.e. have *all* columns in two rows exactly the same values? As already mentioned, this cannot be, because `UNION` prevents that and `DISTINCT` does so, too. On a side note: Why the m1 join? You are not using m1 anywhere in your query. If you simply want to ensure a matching row exists, better use `EXISTS` or `IN` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this block ?

```
select distinct * from(select distinct m2.musteri_id,
             m2.musteri_versiyon,
             m2.musteri_kod,
             m2.musteri_ad as musteri_ad,
             m2.tck_no,
             m2.vkn_no,
             m2.pasaport_no,
             m2.istisna_kod,
             b.banka_kod,
             bs.sube_kod
        from banka b
       inner join banka_sube bs
          on (bs.banka_id = b.banka_id)
       inner join musteri_rol mrb
          on (mrb.musteri_rol_id = b.banka_id)
       inner join musteri m1
          on (m1.musteri_id = mrb.musteri_id)
       inner join musteri_rol mrs
          on (mrs.musteri_rol_id = bs.sube_id)
       inner join musteri m2
          on (m2.musteri_id = mrs.musteri_id)
       where ((m2.musteri_ad like
             '%' || 'GARANTİ' || '%') and 'GARANTİ' is not null)
             and( m2.vkn_no is  null or b.banka_kod is  null or bs.sube_kod is  null)
      union
      select distinct m.musteri_id,
             m.musteri_versiyon,
             m.musteri_kod,
             m.musteri_ad,
             m.tck_no,
             m.vkn_no,
             m.pasaport_no,
             m.istisna_kod,
             null banka_kod,
             null sune_kod
        from musteri_rol mr
       inner join musteri m
          on (m.musteri_id = mr.musteri_id)
       where mr.rol_id = 2701      
         and (m.musteri_ad like '%' || 'GARANTİ' || '%' and
             'GARANTİ' is not null or 'GARANTİ' is null)
) x
```

Comment: can you send me script from part of your database about this table?

Comment: what do you mean.

Comment: can u send me values of your table ? for testing

Comment: musteri_id :40864 musteri_kod :40864 musteri_ad :xx musteri_id :40865 musteri_kod :40865 musteri_ad :yy musteri_id :40865 musteri_kod :40865 musteri_ad :yy

Comment: I need create table script and insert values for test.These values not enough.

Answer (score 0):

when you use distinct, it includes all column, not only 
(musteri_id,musteri_kod,musteri_ad)
you can try it :

```
 with cte as (
 select row_number() over(partition by musteri_id,musteri_kod,musteri_ad order by musteri_id,musteri_kod,musteri_ad)rnum, m2.musteri_id,
             m2.musteri_versiyon,
             m2.musteri_kod,
             m2.musteri_ad as musteri_ad,
             m2.tck_no,
             m2.vkn_no,
             m2.pasaport_no,
             m2.istisna_kod,
             b.banka_kod,
             bs.sube_kod
        from banka b
       inner join banka_sube bs
          on (bs.banka_id = b.banka_id)
       inner join musteri_rol mrb
          on (mrb.musteri_rol_id = b.banka_id)
       inner join musteri m1
          on (m1.musteri_id = mrb.musteri_id)
       inner join musteri_rol mrs
          on (mrs.musteri_rol_id = bs.sube_id)
       inner join musteri m2
          on (m2.musteri_id = mrs.musteri_id)
       where ((m2.musteri_ad like
             '%' || 'GARANTİ' || '%') and 'GARANTİ' is not null) )
,cte1 as (
 select  row_number() over(partition by musteri_id,musteri_kod,musteri_ad order by musteri_id,musteri_kod,musteri_ad)rnum ,m.musteri_id,
             m.musteri_versiyon,
             m.musteri_kod,
             m.musteri_ad,
             m.tck_no,
             m.vkn_no,
             m.pasaport_no,
             m.istisna_kod,
             null banka_kod,
             null sune_kod
        from musteri_rol mr
       inner join musteri m
          on (m.musteri_id = mr.musteri_id)
       where mr.rol_id = 2701      
         and (m.musteri_ad like '%' || 'GARANTİ' || '%' and
             'GARANTİ' is not null or 'GARANTİ' is null)
)
             select * from cte where rnum = 1
             union 
             select * from cte1 where rnum = 1
```

Comment: ok sir but where is the union i need the other table's values.